# Which research article showed that East Asian parents used verbs more to their infants and toddlers?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, developmental-psychology, language, mathematical-ability, cognitive-development

Which research article showed that East Asian parents used verbs more while White parents used adjectives more and had implications for causal and math learning?

Please give the citation of the relevant article.

Comment: Hi Lucy, welcome at CogSci. Do you have any more information about the study you are looking for? Any additional details could help finding the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[**Dimensions of Human Behavior: The Changing Life Course
By Elizabeth D. Hutchison** Chapter Language skills](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OKqZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT266&lpg=PT266&dq=asians%20parents%20using%20more%20verbs&source=bl&ots=jOpHOokUwb&sig=f_HRs7_pKjZPJ4rbd_rri1QLNIc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHkr_yucvQAhVFDMAKHWZHAGgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=asians%20parents%20using%20more%20verbs&f=false)
[image]

Hoff, E. (2006). How social contexts support and shape language development. Developmental Review, 26(1), 55-88.

Comment: how is this paper received?